# Pandas replace in Data frame values which are contains in specific range

Tags: python, pandas

I have this Pandas Data Frame

```
Months  2022-10 2022-11 2022-12 2023-01   …
2023-01   10      N/A     12       13     …
2022-12   2       14      14       N/A    …
2022-11   N/A     11      N/A      N/A    …
2022-10   12      N/A     N/A      N/A    …
…         …       …        …       …
```

I would like to replace the values inside the "date range" by 0 and outside the "date range" with blanks like this in this example:

```
Months  2022-10 2022-11 2022-12 2023-01   …
2023-01   10      0       12       13     …
2022-12   2       14      14              …
2022-11   0       11                      …
2022-10   12                              …
…         …       …        …       …
```

How can I do this with Python Pandas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html) with mask:

```
#if necessary
#df = df.replace('N/A', np.nan)

df2 = df.mask(df.bfill(axis=1).notna() & df.isna(), 0)
print (df2)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      0.0     12.0     13.0
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      0.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10     12.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

**Explanation**:

First back filling missing values:

```
print (df.bfill(axis=1))
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0     12.0     12.0     13.0
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11     11.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10     12.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
```

Then test non missing values:

```
print (df.bfill(axis=1).notna())
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     True     True     True     True
2022-12     True     True     True    False
2022-11     True     True    False    False
2022-10     True    False    False    False
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
```

Chain with testing missing values, so get values for replace by `0`:

```
print (df.bfill(axis=1).notna() & df.isna())
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01    False     True    False    False
2022-12    False    False    False    False
2022-11     True    False    False    False
2022-10    False    False    False    False
```

---

Another idea with numpy broadcasting is compare columns and index `DatatimeIndex` chained with test missing values:

```
c = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_numpy()
r = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_numpy()

m = (c <= r[:, None]) & df.isna()
print (m)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01    False     True    False    False
2022-12    False    False    False    False
2022-11     True    False    False    False
2022-10    False    False    False    False

df1 = df.mask(m, 0)
print (df1)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      0.0     12.0     13.0
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      0.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10     12.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Solutions are different if last values per range are missing values:

```
print (df)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      NaN     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN


c = pd.to_datetime(df.columns).to_numpy()
r = pd.to_datetime(df.index).to_numpy()

m = (c <= r[:, None]) & df.isna()
df1 = df.mask(m, 0)
print (df1)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      0.0      0.0      0.0
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      0.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10      0.0      NaN      NaN      NaN

df2 = df.mask(df.bfill(axis=1).notna() & df.isna(), 0)
print (df2)
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      0.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN
```

Comment: Perfect explanation and solution, thanks!

Comment: @SimonGIS - added new solution and also difference of solutions. You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

One option for in place substitution using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df[df.bfill(axis=1).notna()] = df.fillna(0)
```

Output:

```
         2022-10  2022-11  2022-12  2023-01
Months                                     
2023-01     10.0      0.0     12.0     13.0
2022-12      2.0     14.0     14.0      NaN
2022-11      0.0     11.0      NaN      NaN
2022-10     12.0      NaN      NaN      NaN
```